# Binomial distribution sampling - concrete example

Tags: lwe, ring-lwe, newhope

Can anyone give me an explicit example of how one can samples from the binomial distribution defined in NewHope's paper? What is the difference of sampling from rounded Gaussian in practice?

Comment: Isn't this a completely probability question about distributions?

Comment: Isn't their distribution $\sum_{i = 1}^n (X_i - Y_i)$ where $X_i, Y_i\sim\mathsf{Bern}(1/2)$ i.i.d.?